# What does this code snipe do or is it just a mistake

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I learn Reactjs and read lots of code and cant make this out.
Is this a mistake in the code or does it do something;

I mean this line:

```
this.props.onEnd && this.props.onEnd();
```

I know the `onEnd()` is a callback to parent but how does it work looking like this?
Code;

```
/**
 *  Let parent components know that we reached the end of display
 */
_onEnd(isVisible) {
    if (!isVisible) return;
    this.props.onEnd && this.props.onEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's equivalent to saying this:

```
if (this.props.onEnd != null) {   // validate not null or undefined
    this.props.onEnd();           // execute function
}
```

When expressed as follows:

```
this.props.onEnd && this.props.onEnd();
```

The expression will short circuit if `onEnd` is null or undefined.  If it is, then the expression evaluates logically as:

```
false && this.props.onEnd()
```

In which case since `false && <anything else>` will always evaluate to `false`. The runtime won't evaluate the call on the right if the left of the **and** operator evaluates to false.

Similarly, if `onEnd` is valid, then it logically gets evaluated as:

```
true && this.props.onEnd()
```

In which case, `this.props.onEnd()` is evaluated and executed.

For more information, look up up [boolean short circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) as an internet search.

Comment: I change the code to `const { onEnd } = this.props; onEnd && onEnd();` Then Eslint was not happy again "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.eslintno-unused-expressions" Eslint dont like short circuit but I do! lol